# OpenCL execution strategy for tree like dependency graph

Tags: tree, opencl

I'm attempting to use OpenCL to process data which is best modeled as an inverted tree structure (with the root at the bottom, like a physical tree), where each node in the tree depends on processed data from its child leaf nodes above it. Nodes on different branches can execute in parallel, but those on the same branch (ancestors) must be executed serially. The processing is done at regular time slices, for real-time data streaming. My question is in regards to how to best structure this with OpenCL, command queues, work groups, and work items.

The data is actually several trees (sub trees) of varying size which are all processed at the end into a final result, which is copied back to the host. Each node "outputs" a fixed size buffer of floating point data (which may come from a child node or a global buffer). The size of these buffers is globally the same for all nodes (64 elements for example).

I had first thought to structure it to where each work item is an individual data value in the buffers. However, each of the node processes consists of many conditional computation stages, many of which vary from node to node and some filter stages may require values from other indexes. This seems to rule out a completely data parallel model.

So I then thought that each of the sub trees could be allocated to a work group with the individual nodes being the work items. This seems to make sense as far as buffers are concerned because the nodes in each sub tree will be frequently sharing result data buffers between each other (local data). The problem with this is that each sub tree can have a different number of nodes (work items), and I think OpenCL needs to have the same work items per group, which are wasted if not being used. The dependency graph also varies, which probably rules out the use of barriers as a useful synchronization mechanism. Dependencies could be handled with event lists and waits in the command queue, but I'm trying to avoid this, for performance reasons. So this also doesn't seem like the right solution.

The final solution I am thinking of now, is to just make each sub-tree a single work item per group. I think this is more of a parallel task approach, but could still take advantage of SIMD operations in loops, and multiple compute cores.

Does this final solution seem like the best way to model this? Or does anyone have any better ideas of how to improve parallel execution?

Comment: What is OpenCL?

Comment: Open Compute Language. It's used for running computation intensive applications on GPUs, DSPs, and even just CPUs.

Comment: This is unfortunately a rather high-level and vague question, which makes it very hard to answer. To improve your chances of getting help here, I suggest you go into more detail: 1. What hardware are you planning to run this on? (e.g. CPU, discrete desktop GPU, iGPU, etc.)

Comment: 2. *"However, each of the node processes consists of many conditional computation stages, many of which vary from node to node and some filter stages may require values from other indexes."* Can you elaborate on this please? Conditionals in compute kernels aren't necessarily a fundamental problem. It mainly depends on the clustering of decisions, the hardware, and the type of computation you're performing.

Comment: 3. What kind of processing is done at each node? How much data is being processed, roughly how many operations are we expecting?

Comment: 4. I assume you have an existing implementation of this written in a scalar programming language. What sort of performance are you getting there and what are you trying to achieve by moving to OpenCL?

Comment: @pmdj Thank you for your helpful comments. I realize this question was likely a bit too vague and I probably should have waited till I had already attempted a solution. I currently have a multi-threaded implementation in C which I have run on X86 desktops and an embedded ARM system. My intent is to be able to offload the computation to NVIDIA or other GPUs and embedded Ti C66x DSP platforms. I'm currently far along in an OpenCL solution using the 3rd option I mentioned (1 work item per group) and will see how well it performs shortly.

Comment: In the meantime, I'm not sure what to do with this question. Since it isn't very specific in its current form and I think I am proceeding down the proper path to a solution, should I just delete it?